# How to to define bamboo artifact so its NOT published in syb folder

Tags: bamboo, artifact, bamboo-specs, bamboo-artifacts

The artifact definition and the file structure in the bitbucket repository is as below.
The build when run creates application-dev.properties &  safeguard-dev.properties under classes folder. When i click them it takes me to classes folder inside which the property files are present. But i want them to be published directly like the jar. So that when I click the file it should download. But if i give full path it errors out. Please help me how to define this?

error   19-Dec-2022 16:34:57    Failing as no matching files has been found and empty artifacts are not allowed.
error   19-Dec-2022 16:34:57    Unable to publish artifact [application-dev.properties]:
error   19-Dec-2022 16:34:57    The artifact is required, build will now fail.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo won't put the artifacts in a subfolder if the "Location" points to exactly where the files are. I.e. don't use the "**" wildcard in the "Copy pattern". I'd say try even to have a separate artifact per properties file.

Your location is pointing to "workdir/src", but you need "target/classes". Get rid of the $bamboo.build.working.directory: that's not the maven build dir and you don't need it altogether (because current work dir is already set to your project dir). If I get the paths right, this should work:

```
Name: application-dev.properties
Location: target/classes
Copy pattern: application-dev.properties
```